# Would this be better off on Stack Overflow than Super User or both?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, cross-posting

https://superuser.com/questions/1116663/single-step-word-styles-from-source-document-through-entire-destination-document

Now, I read this: 
https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4836/what-is-the-difference-between-super-user-and-stack-overflow

Now, I am not sure whether the solution involves:

- Some simple Word Macros **(aka Power user)** or
- Some more powerful scripting around VBA (VB for Office Apps), VBS and/ or Batch/ Powershell stuff **(SO domain)**.
- Or there it can be done "both ways"?

Should I/ Am I allowed to cross post at both places to get answers of both flavors?

Comment: It is not a programming question, this can be done with point and click inside Word.  You'll just have to wait until a superuser.com contributor tells you how to use a document template so you only have to do the clicking once.  But a bounty on it when nobody can find that time.

Comment: @HansPassant - Pleasr point me to a link that might lead to a point & single click solution. Given what I'm trying to achieve (repeatedly apply "Bullet style" (w/o overwrite or remove other styles) thru entire destination document) it might be more VBA/ VB script than word.

Answer (score 3):

You are not allowed to post *the same* question on different Stack Exchange sites; this is known as [cross-posting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/cross-posting/info). Of course, if you specify you want it done in Word on SuperUser, and in VBA in Stack Overflow, that makes it two different questions. Just make sure that your question is [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); a question like

> How do I do X with VBA?

is way too broad for Stack Overflow - you should include at least what you've tried so far and where you're stuck. I assume the same policy applies to SuperUser.

Comment: This is a post processing step, that I was unable to perform due to limitations of XML/XSL that I have/ using to generate the Destination Doc. Beyond it I'm trying to figure out what approach to take - Will try the SU way and then come out to SO with what I've tried thus far.